# Bouncy not works with subdomains

Tags: node.js, proxy, subdomain, forever

I'm using [Bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) on my server. But it not works with subdomains.

My script:

```
var bouncy = require('bouncy');

var server = bouncy(function (req, res, bounce) {
    if (req.headers.host === 'www.example.com') {
        bounce(8001);

    } else if (req.headers.host === 'sub.example.com') {
        bounce(8002);

    } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end('no such host');
    }
});
server.listen(80);
```

When I visit `www.example.com` I see my page. But when I visit `sub.example.com` Forever throw me error

```
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL
error: Script restart attempt #1
```

Who knows how to solve this issue?